# Java regex to match a word that occurs at least twice

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to match words that occur more than once. For example:
in the String "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Try to find the Text".
I'm trying to match words like `"the"`, `"Text"`, and maybe `"to"`.

Regex tried:

```
([A-Za-z])\w+{1,}
(([A-Za-z])\w+)+?
```

Comment: Maybe `to`? Why would you not want to find just that word?

Comment: I just want to add that it might be possible in the "extended" means of regex, as it was extended in some languages - but the traditional theoretical regex, that stands for "Regular Expression", as in "Regular Language" - it cannot be done, because the language .*w.*w.* is not regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to find all repeated words:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR6aH5/1)

You will need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs and `Matcher#find` method to get all words using a loop.

Comment: I just want to add that it might be possible in the "extended" means of regex, as it was extended in some languages - but the traditional theoretical regex, that stands for "Regular Expression", as in "Regular Language" - it cannot be done, because the language .*w.*w.* is not regular.

Comment: Yes but question is tagged as Java and this is very much possible in Java regex.

Comment: I am not criticizing the answer in any way, just contributing more information.

Comment: That worked for me thanks. I'll also have a look at that site you posted in the future